# ubuntu Chmod -R 777 /

Tags: ubuntu, chmod

I wanted to use the command Chmod -R 777 ./ but made a mistake and gave access rights to /.

Now I can not connect via ssh:Network error: Software caused connection abort
Tell me how to restore everything as it was

Comment: This is not a programming question. I suggest deleting it here and posting in [ubuntu.se] or [unix.se]. Also, `chmod -R 777` is overkill even if you only do it on a single directory. It makes all files readable and executable by all users.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know you can do the next:

- Login to the console as `root`
- Have other machine with proper permissions
- Check the proper permissions and set on messed machine